# Evaluation order in WHERE clause and really slow query

Tags: sql, t-sql, database-design

```
SELECT ... WHERE expr1 and expr2 or expr3 or expr4
```

this query executes in > 3 minutes.

```
SELECT ... WHERE expr1 and (expr2 or expr3 or expr4)
```

this terminates instantly.

I would have expected different *results*, not different *performance*. Can anybody explain why?

**Background**: the select *left outer joins* 7 tables, but they are not very large (< 10k records the biggest one). [Here is the query](http://pastebin.com/UY70bwrN), but I strongly advise that it's unintelligible because it's generated from a very old tool on a legacy system and the overall project is very difficult to work with. I am only interested in the question descrived above

Comment: What does the query plan tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second version requires that `expr1` be true for all records. If `expr1` depends only on a single table, then the DBMS can ["push" the predicate "down"](https://www.google.com/search?q=predicate%20pushdown) and do that filtering before even performing the joins. (Even if it depends on multiple tables, it can at least be pushed down before *some* of the joins.) This potentially allows *many* fewer records to be examined, and much better use of indices.

Comment: @MartinSmith: No, it doesn't. `WHERE expr1 and expr2 or expr3 or expr4` means `WHERE (expr1 and expr2) or expr3 or expr4`: it's satisfied if `expr3` is true for a given record, even if `expr1` is false.

Comment: So the second query takes advantage of `expr1` to execute fast, while the first one suffers from `expr2`/`expr3`/`expr4` being slow

Comment: @Raffaele: Not exactly. It's more that the second query takes advantage of the fact that `expr1` can be computed earlier on, so that a lot less joining has to take place. The first one suffers from the fact that it needs to evaluate `expr1 and expr2 or expr3 or expr4` on many more records, after performing many more joins.

Comment: Technically speaking, the same should apply to the first query, ie the db could check e1 and e2 before joining. In this case the problem is with e3 or e4, since it can early evaluate e1 but must check the other expressions to reject the record

Answer (score 2):

`OR` comparisons take a long time, since you need to check every record for every possibility.

Encasing the `OR`s in parentheses treats them as a set and allows short-circuiting evaluations.

Your first query evaluates as:

```
WHERE (Expr1 --required
AND   Expr2) --required
OR    Expr3 --but you can skip those to find this
OR    Expr4 --or this
```

It takes more time to check all 3 conditions.

Your second evaluates Expr1, then can quickly check three conditions in the subset.  I'm guessing that one of those is indexed and can be checked very efficiently, which reduces the result set needed to check for the others.

Comment: I don't understand :/ If expr3 and expr4 are the fastest to check, the former should execute more quickly because it can skip expr1 and expr2 and directly jump to expr3/expr4. But I guess I didn't understand your answer...

Comment: Sorry, the first query requires `(expr1 AND expr2)` OR (one of the other 2).  It `expr1` or `expr2` could be quickest to check individually, but the other is slow so the first query is slow.  Since they are separated in the second query, the "faster" one can be checked first.

Comment: Eventually, you are stating that `expr2` is slow, but in the former it's always evaluated (because the optimzer finds that anyway `e1 and e2` is quicker than `e3` and quicker than `e4`) while in the latter it's skipped because `e1` is a required condition and it can be evaluated quickly. Right?

Comment: expr2 or expr1 could be slow, I don't know which. It's not possible to tell with the info given.  It does seem that ONE of them is much slower than the other.  The first query needs to check both, the second does not.  there's also no way to know what order the evaluations are done in the query engine since they aren't in sequential order necessarily.

Comment: I think actually `expr1` must be the faster one, because in the second query it's required so must be evaluated for each record in the set. Isn't it?